# How to create multiple objects of a class at once

Tags: python-3.x, oop

When I was learning C++ Object oriented programming, I used to use following statements to create multiple objects:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    obj[i] = MyClass()
}
```

which creates 5 objects of class `MyClass()`

I tried similar thing in python but didn't work

```
class c1:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Object Created")

for i in range(0, 10):
    e[i] = c1()
```

It gives me `NameError: name 'e' is not defined`.

Thank You

Comment: The indentation is wrong... and you never defined `e`...

Comment: Simply use `e = [c1() for _ in range(5)]`. This is more or less the equivalent.

Comment: OK! That helps. **Thank You**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues are there 
1. Indentation on second line is wrong
2. You didn't define e

Try this;

```
class c1:
  def __init__(self):
    print("Object Created")

e=[c1() for _ in range(10)]
```

Comment: You created a list of c1`s... then overwrote them with new c1`s.

Comment: Well, don't do that.

Comment: Why do you do that?

Comment: Ooopppppsss... I am so sorry. I was just out of my mind. Updated the answer. :p

Comment: Why that extra `for` loop is required?

Comment: Now there is only one for loop. Updated my answer.

Comment: Now how to access that data? Suppose I have list of names like `name = ["john", "mike", "soniya"]` and I want to create objects for each of these names. I used loop `for i in range (0, len(name)):` , `e = c1(name[i])` to create and assign each object with name in list. When I try to display the names of each object using similar for loop `for i in range(0, len(name))` and display function `e.display()` which is a member function of class `c1`, it only gives me the name of last object. So how do I create individual objects with their individual data?

Comment: Does this loop thing to create multiple objects actually creates individual objects or it overwrites each other? Because It displays the name of objects which was assigned at the last